# How can I embed content from my blog to my Google+ Page

Tags: wordpress, google-plus

I have a wordpress.com blog. I would like to link it to my Google+ page so the posts are embeded. How to I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to place below url into your href:

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=<ur_permalink>
```

your permalink.

Also need to include google plus js and script also